# Getting "invalid context" error with UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to make this draw a line where the pan gesture happens. The problem is when I try to use this code

```
var firstPoint: CGPoint!

var path: UIBezierPath!

@IBAction func panned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .Began: firstPoint = gesture.locationOfTouch(0, inView: view)
    case .Ended: gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    case .Changed:
        path.moveToPoint(firstPoint)
        path.addLineToPoint(gesture.translationInView(view))
        path.stroke()
    default: break
    }
}
```

...I get multiple errors which I am not quite sure what to do about.

```
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
Apr 2 17:40:03 MacBook-Pro.local Paint[6729] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is telling you that you are trying to call CoreGraphics functions outside of a valid context (a `CGContextRef`). You should not call `stroke` unless you're doing it within the `drawRect` of `UIView` subclass or between `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` (or something equivalent). But you cannot just `stroke` a path if you are not within a graphics context.

If you just want to add this path to a `UIView`, you can also create a `CAShapeLayer`, and use the `cgPath` of this bezier path, and take the resulting `CAShapeLayer` and add it as a sublayer of the view's layer. For example, in Swift 3 and later:

```
var drawPath: UIBezierPath!
var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)

    if gesture.state == .began {
        drawPath = UIBezierPath()
        drawPath.move(to: location)

        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
        gesture.view?.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    } else if gesture.state == .changed {
        drawPath.addLine(to: location)
        shapeLayer.path = drawPath.cgPath
    }
}
```